# CANNON.JS angular velocity behaving strange

Tags: angularjs, three.js, velocity, cannon.js

I'm currently experimenting a bit with three.js and cannon.js.

I have an object like so:

```
var ship = {
    mesh: new THREE.Mesh(); //let's pretend there's a mesh in there.
    rigidBody: new CANNON.RigidBody(); //let's pretend there's a rigid body in here.
};
```

On the update function i rotate the mesh to the rotation of the rigid body, like so:

```
var update = function(){
    ship.mesh.rotation.x = ship.rigidBody.quaternion.x;
    ship.mesh.rotation.y = ship.rigidBody.quaternion.y;
    ship.mesh.rotation.z = ship.rigidBody.quaternion.z;
};
```

This all works fine, the problem is when i define an angular velocity.

```
ship.rigidBody.angularVelocity.z = 1; //for example
```

I figured the object would start rotating until the angular velocity reaches 0, but it just kinda sways back and forth. can anyone be so kind and explain why this is happening, and perhaps give a solution to keep the object rotating?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be doing this instead:

```
var update = function(){
    ship.mesh.quaternion.x = ship.rigidBody.quaternion.x;
    ship.mesh.quaternion.y = ship.rigidBody.quaternion.y;
    ship.mesh.quaternion.z = ship.rigidBody.quaternion.z;
    ship.mesh.quaternion.w = ship.rigidBody.quaternion.w;
};
```

Comment: How about `ship.mesh.quaternion.copy( ship.rigidBody.quaternion );` ?

Comment: @WestLangley that works on r68dev but not on r67 (my fault :/).